# Eliminar todos los datos de un fichero

Tags: java, archivo, eclipse, eliminar

Hola tengo que eliminar todo los datos de un fichero tengo esto

```
public void Borrar(File archivo){
        if (!archivo.exists()) {
            System.out.println("El archivo data no existe.");
        } else {
            archivo.delete();
            System.out.println("El archivo data fue eliminado.");
        }
}
```

pero al correrlo me dice que ya se elimino pero los datos siguen dentro del txt, lo intente de otra forma y me decia que no se podian eliminar(use un try catch), lei por ahi que tengo que darle permisos pero no entiendo el como hacerlo es una de las cosas que me fallan, la ruta no creo que sea porque no me ah dado problema en agregar datos o mostrarlos solo tengo pedos en eliminar por completo todo lo que tiene el archivo
gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que estas preguntando es como borrar los contenidos de un fichero y no el fichero en si.

Para que entiendas un poco lo que tú estas intentando hacer ahora mismo es eliminar el fichero, si lo que quieres es eliminar su contenido debes usar una de las muchas clases que tiene Java para tratar con el contenido de ficheros.

Yo voy a usar la clase `FileWriter`, la solución es la siguiente:

```java
public static void borrar(File archivo) {
    if (!archivo.exists()) { // Si el fichero no existe no hacemos nada.
        System.out.println("El archivo data no existe.");
    } else { // Si el fichero existe, se lo pasamos al constructor de FileWriter
        FileWriter fw;
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(archivo);
            fw.flush(); // Vaciamos el fichero        
            fw.close(); // Cerramos el "canal de comunicación" con el fichero

            System.out.println("El archivo data fue eliminado.");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error al borrar contenido del fichero");
        }            
    }
}
```

De esta forma dejamos el fichero sin eliminar pero si que eliminamos su contenido. En java tenemos muchas otras formas de hacer esto, te dejo el siguiente enlace para que vayas leyendo al respecto.

- http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Lectura_y_Escritura_de_Ficheros_en_Java